# Apply Trailing Slash to Folders with FilesystemIterator

Tags: php, filesystems, iterator, spl

Having the following snippet to map the contents of the current directory recursively:

```
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator
(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('./',
        FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS | FilesystemIterator::UNIX_PATHS),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);

$files = array_values(array_map('strval', iterator_to_array($files)));
```

Returns something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ./1.png
    [1] => ./a.php
    [2] => ./adminer
    [3] => ./adminer/adminer.css
    [4] => ./adminer/adminer.php
)
```

Is there any way I can get [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) / [`FilesystemIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php) to emulate the `GLOB_MARK` behavior that exists in the [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function? From the manual:

> **GLOB_MARK** - Adds a slash to each directory returned.

I know I could emulate that by simply doing:

```
foreach ($files as $key => $value)
{
    $files[$key] .= (is_dir($value) ? '/' : '');
}
```

But that would require (unnecessarily?) hitting the disk lots of times. I'm looking for a way to quickly determine if the path is a directory or a regular file, and the ending slash seems like the ideal solution.

I plan to traverse tens (if not hundreds) of thousands of files with this, so performance is critical.

**Bonus question: Is there any way to get only the directories (recursively)?**

Comment: Do you mind a solution that extends `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` ??

Comment: @Baba: Not at all, but note that calling `isDir()` in there is cheating! :P

Comment: I know .... i also want to cheat ... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own `GlobMarkIterator` advantages :

- Returns Ending Slashes to directory just as `GLOB_MARK`
- No need of using `array_map` with `strval` to convert it to string
- No extra `foreach` loop with `is_dir`
- Still as fast as the original
- **Yes I know I cheated**

Example

```
$ri = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new GlobMarkIterator('./', FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS | FilesystemIterator::UNIX_PATHS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
$files = array_values(iterator_to_array($ri));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($files);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => ./test/backups/ <----------- Note ending slash 
    [1] => ./test/CSV/
    [2] => ./test/CSV/abc.csv
    [3] => ./test/final/
    [4] => ./test/thumb/
    [5] => ./test/thumb/a.png
    [6] => ./test/thumb/s.svg
    [7] => ./test/thumb/sample.svg
)
```

**Bonus question: Is there any way to get only the directories (recursively)?**

This should have been another question but all the same .... *I hope you don't get satisfied and put a bounty on this*

Solution :

```
$ri = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new GlobMarkDirectory('./test'), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
$dir = array_values(iterator_to_array($ri));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($dir);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => ./test/backups/
    [1] => ./test/CSV/
    [2] => ./test/final/
    [3] => ./test/thumb/
)
```

Class Used

`GlobMarkIterator`

```
class GlobMarkIterator extends RecursiveDirectoryIterator {
    function current() {
        return $this->isDir() ? $this->getPathname() . "/" : $this->getPathname();
    }
}
```

`GlobMarkDirectory` Class

```
class GlobMarkDirectory  extends RecursiveFilterIterator {
    public function __construct($path) {
        parent::__construct(new GlobMarkIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS | FilesystemIterator::UNIX_PATHS));
    }
    public function accept() {
        return $this->getInnerIterator()->isDir();
    }
    public function getChildren() {
        return new GlobMarkDirectory($this->getInnerIterator()->getPathname());
    }
}
```

**EDIT .. if you don't care about `empty dir` and you don't want to use `isDir` due to speed and overhead here is another solution**

Solution

```
$ri = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new GlobMarkFastDirectory  (__DIR__), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
$dir = array_values(array_unique(iterator_to_array($ri)));
```

`GlobMarkFastDirectory`

```
class GlobMarkFastDirectory  extends RecursiveDirectoryIterator {
    function current() {
        return dirname($this->getPathname())  ."/";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is it really as fast as the barebone? What if I have to call `isDir()` on 145.684 files? `RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST` places directories first, couldn't that be exploited in some way, using `next()` for instance? Also, would the `getChildren()` / `hasChildren()` methods offer any benefit over `isDir()`? My impression is that `isDir()` issues yet another disk call, but I might be wrong on this.

Comment: that can be exploited too but the issue is that next can be very tricky due to position management ..... `isDir` is different from `SplFileInfo::isDir` .. Type has already been determined before it was called .. every file in  `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`  returns `SplFileInfo` .. it already know if its a file or directory ... its not searching or locating the file again

Comment: In that case, this is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Just added the solution to your bonus question  :)

Comment: I noticed! Regarding "Type has already been determined before it was called" a friend of mine just pointed me to these LOCs: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/spl/spl_directory.c#L1225 and https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/filestat.c#L1160 so I guess that's not exactly accurate, but apparently `glob` does the same thing: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/win32/glob.c#L570.

Comment: I had an idea, since I need to traverse the result anyway I might as well use the `RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY` flag and add the directories as I go with `dirname` (or the SPL equivalent).

Comment: Just tested with `RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY` and it sill gives me files ... ??? Have you tested it .. make sure they are files on the initial dir too

Comment: Yup. Anyway, check my answer for an alternative solution. It solves both problems without hitting the disk more than it should.

Answer (score 1):

This is my best effort so far:

```
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator
(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator
    (
        str_replace('\\', '/', realpath('./')),
        FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS | FilesystemIterator::UNIX_PATHS
    ),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

$files = array_keys(iterator_to_array($files));
$folders = array();

/*
foreach ($files as $key => $value) // not needed anymore
{
    $files[$key] .= (is_dir($value) === true) ? '/' : '';
}
*/

$files = array_flip($files);

foreach ($files as $key => $value)
{
    $folder = dirname($key) . '/'; // doesn't issue a stat call

    if (array_key_exists($folder, $folders) !== true)
    {
        $folders[$folder] = 0;
    }

    $folders[$folder] += $files[$key] = sprintf('%u', filesize($key));
}
```

I could merge the `$folders` array with the `$files` array to answer the question precisely, but distinguishing one of the other was exactly my main objective, so there's no point in doing that.

Comment: @Baba: This is just a proof of concept. It runs 47k files in less than 10 seconds, but I will polish the raw edges eventually. =)

Comment: +1 for not using `isDir`  ... Let me see how i can improve on it  :)

Comment: I just observed an array with your script .. its skipping some directory

Comment: What i mean is `skip empty folders`

Comment: @Baba: Indeed, but I intend to use this to build a better-than-average script to identify duplicated folders, files and code - so that's not a big problem in this case.

Comment: have been able to come up with a faster approach see updated code

Comment: @Baba: BTW I just ran a benchmark (3 iterations on 47k files) for my approach without the `filesize` call and for the `GlobMarkIterator` (I didn't ran the `GlobMarkDirectory` one) and the results I got were: `[m1] => 26.016923904419` and `[m2] => 29.191436052322` (`GlobMarkIterator`) so it's not too bad.

Comment: Just updated with a faster solution .. trust me .. you would smile `GlobMarkFastDirectory`

Comment: Am talking about directory alone now , Try `AlexIterator` (Yours) , `GlobMarkFastDirectory` .. its much more faster

Comment: @Baba: Sorry it took me so long to reply, I was running the benchmark when I realized I had it wrong and had to redo the whole thing... Anyway, here it is: https://gist.github.com/1550b1fb121d1fa84cfc#file_results.txt, I optimized my code a little (`array_values` + `array_map` to `array_keys` and dropped the `array_flip` since that's extra compared to your approach) but as you can see the difference is negligible.

Comment: @Bab: Yes, I'm satisfied now. =) Thank you so much for your time and help!